# On an Angular form how to disable submit button when a formControl.status === 'DISABLED'

Tags: angular

I need to disable submit button (Accept Button) when these two conditions meet:

1. form.valid !== true or what is the same !form.valid
2. formControl ProductType status is not disabled

   ```
   this.form.controls.productType.status !== 'DISABLED'
   ```

ProductType is a required formControl, so it has to have a value for form.valid to be true. The problem comes when productType formControl is disabled momentarily when changing the value of its grandfather formControl. I need this behavior to force the user to fill up the fields in this order: Category > Family > ProductType

[image]

In this moment, although ProductType formControl is required, as its status is DISABLED, it´s like it doesnt count and the condition form.valid is true. Anyway when productType formControl is disable I need to disable the submit button. I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
<button type="button" 
        [disabled]="!form.valid && form.controls.productType.status !== 'DISABLED'" 
        (click)="submit()">
</button>
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: Disabled fields are not submitted in forms and therefore typically are not validated. I would suggest using a separate property on the model to control that piece of the validation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Could you please include an example of that idea? I dont know what you mean

Comment: Just a property on the controller like `productTypeDisabled: boolean;`. You set it to true or false as needed. On the ProductType control, bind `[disabled]="productTypeDisabled"` and on the button, `[disabled]="!form.valid && productTypeDisabled"`.

Answer (score 1):

every form control have a **disabled** property that you can check if he true or false.

so try this:

```
<button type="button" 
        [disabled]="!form.valid && !form.controls.productType.disabled" 
        (click)="submit()">
</button>
```

for more info you can go here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: This code was exactly what I tried but nothing